Is there a community wiki for Quantitative Finance forum of StackExchange?
If so, how could I access it? Some post was mentioning it but I couldn't find a link to it in FAQ or the first page of the forum.

That doesn't exist, that post probably mentioned Community Wiki question. A Community Wiki question is a question that doesn't have one authoritative answer but it can be a list or something, check out this question.
